# My html file does not recognize javascript files or javascript inserted code

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i am developing a dashboard in angular 10, and i am using chart.js to build some charts.
my dashboard.component.html doesnt recognize my javascript file. I also tried to use the tag  and insert the code directly in the html file, still nothing. What can i do?

my files:

```js
var IAP = document.getElementById('IAP').getContext('2d');
    var IapChart = new Chart(IAP, {
      type:'bar',
      data={
        labels:[ 'Aveiro', 'Beja', 'Braga', 'Bragança', 'Castelo Branco', 'Coimbra', 'Évora', 'Faro', 'Guarda',
        'Leiria', 'Lisboa', 'Portalegre', 'Porto', 'Santarém', 'Setúbal', 'Viana do Castelo', 'Vila Real', 'Viseu'],
        datasets:[{
            label:'IAP',
            data:[1.01,
                  1,20,
                  1,89,
                  1,99,
                  0,88,
                  1,23,
                  1,32,
                  1,67,
                  1,55,
                  0,77,
                  1,38,
                  1,66,
                  1,00,
                  1,11,
                  0,87,
                  1,45,
                  1,12
                  ]
        }]
        },
      options:{},
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>DashBoard</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="IAP"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't loaded the chart.js file in the snippet. As far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Angular, I would suggest that you take advantage of npm to install chart.js library and write a component that handles the chart creation.

It is very simple

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

```
ng g c barchart
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
this.BarChart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type:'bar',
      data: {
        labels:[ 'Aveiro', 'Beja', 'Braga', 'Bragança', 'Castelo Branco', 'Coimbra', 'Évora', 'Faro', 'Guarda',
        'Leiria', 'Lisboa', 'Portalegre', 'Porto', 'Santarém', 'Setúbal', 'Viana do Castelo', 'Vila Real', 'Viseu'],
        datasets:[{
            label:'IAP',
            data:[1.01,
                  1,20,
                  1,89,
                  1,99,
                  0,88,
                  1,23,
                  1,32,
                  1,67,
                  1,55,
                  0,77,
                  1,38,
                  1,66,
                  1,00,
                  1,11,
                  0,87,
                  1,45,
                  1,12
                  ]
        }]
        },
      options:{},
    })
```

The html can be something like this barchart.component.html

```
<div class="chart-container">    
  <canvas id="canvas">{{ BarChart }}</canvas>    
</div>
```

I suggest this because a library import usually done through npm will be optimised at the build step by using tree shaking and other bundlers, while tree shaking is not possible with importing the entire chart.js library in your index.html.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the first part of the code you posted should i use it to replace what i have in barchart.component.ts?
and how can i "import" this to my dashboard component?

Comment: i really cant understand where to use that first snippet of code you posted. I already installed chart.js and created the barchart component. Where do i put that code now? and how can i "call" that to appear in my dashboard? Sorry for all the questions, i am new to angular

Comment: If you already did it just skip the steps 
What I wrote is an approximation not the entire code
And you can use the selector of barchart.component.ts in dashboart.component.html as a HTML tag

Comment: the issue i dont understand here is what will barchart.component.ts look like. I generated it and got the default code. where do i put my js script in there? is it inside export class{}? or before that? or after? is it inside the contructor?

Comment: I finally solved it! thank you guys for all the help! cheers

Answer (score 0):

Found a typo in the code. * data={* is an object key so you must use semicolons : *data: {*.

Here is the working snippet:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var IAP = document.getElementById('IAP').getContext('2d');
    var IapChart = new Chart(IAP, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Aveiro', 'Beja', 'Braga', 'Bragança', 'Castelo Branco', 'Coimbra', 'Évora', 'Faro', 'Guarda',
                'Leiria', 'Lisboa', 'Portalegre', 'Porto', 'Santarém', 'Setúbal', 'Viana do Castelo', 'Vila Real', 'Viseu'
            ],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'IAP',
                data: [1.01,
                    1, 20,
                    1, 89,
                    1, 99,
                    0, 88,
                    1, 23,
                    1, 32,
                    1, 67,
                    1, 55,
                    0, 77,
                    1, 38,
                    1, 66,
                    1, 00,
                    1, 11,
                    0, 87,
                    1, 45,
                    1, 12
                ]
            }]
        },
        options: {},
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport"
         content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
      <title>DashBoard</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <canvas id="IAP"></canvas>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps :)

PS: I suggest you to use [eslint](https://eslint.org) in combination with [Prettier](https://prettier.io) for linting and much more.

Comment: You did help with the typo in the code! :D
But unfortunately i cant still load the chart in my dashboard.

Comment: Added the *[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)* listener.

Comment: it didnt solve it as well. maybe its something to do with the project being angular? i already installed chart.js lib but i cant really find a way to display my js content in the dashboard component

Comment: As @RajaAvinash suggested, you are using angular so you must follow the angular structured on how to import modules. See [this](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages).

Comment: yeah my problem is that im new to angular and most of the problems i encountered were solved by try and error. But this one i cant find a way to display my js script in my dashboard component, something that at first glance should be easy to do..